# How do I select elements when I already have a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have a variable containing a DOM element, and want to select elements related to that DOM element, simply wrap it in a jQuery object.

```
var myDomElement = document.getElementById("foo");
$(myDomElement ).find("a");
```

Many people try to concatenate a DOM element or jQuery object with a CSS selector, like so:

```
$(myDomElement + ".bar" );
```

Unfortunately, you cannot concatenate strings to objects. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you really mean

Comment: Other than the question's title, where is the actual question in the question's body?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you cannot concatenate strings to objects.

In your case you should do this to get the result.

```
$("#" + myDomElement.id + " .bar" );
```

or if you already know the id

```
$("#foo .bar" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to look into `querySelector()`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

In your example:

```
document.querySelector("#foo a");
```